# Trying to build regex need inputs on that

Tags: regex

I am having a string

```
<sip:a39pbx@47.168.156.141:5060;maddr=47.168.156.141>;expires=703,<sip:739pbxast25@47.168.156.141:5060;maddr=47.168.156.141>;expires=826;
```

want to extract expires and its value, I have tried using

```
(.*)(expires=\d*);(.*)
```

But it is giving me only last one which is `expires=826`, I want to select other or also which is ending with `,`.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Not much info from your question, I don't know what you're running your regex with. But I guess \d should be at least \d+

Comment: Why don't you simply use `expires=\d+`?

Answer (score 0):

You should try like:

```
(expires=(\d+)),
```

The last comma will help you to match with the value which ends with `,`. It will give two match one with key & value and another with value only.

#### [Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/RDac86xF2L)

Answer (score 0):

```
(expires=\d+)
```

http://regex101.com/r/sQ5bJ7

```
(expires=\d+)

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(expires=\d+)»
   Match the characters “expires=” literally «expires=»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```